# Cross compiling with mingw64 - wildcard expansion

Tags: fedora, autoconf, mingw-w64

I'm trying to cross compile GNU grep for Windows from Fedora, using their mingw64 cross compilers. The process is really easy, with one exception. By default, it appears that mingw64 doesn't expand wildcards on the command line, so that `grep FOO *` gives "Invalid argument: *" rather than searching all files in the current directory.

After a bit of research, I found that there is an external symbol, `_dowildcard` in the mingw64 CRT, that will trigger wildcard expansion if set to -1. But I've found no useful documentation on how to set this (maybe because it's considered obvious ;-)).

I could modify the source code to set the variable, but I'd much prefer to *not* have to modify the source if at all possible. (I want to set up an automated build, and applying code patches just adds complexity that I'd like to avoid). Is there any way to set `_dowildcard` from the configure or make command line? I seem to remember older versions of mingw having a `setargv.obj` file that could be linked into your project to enable wildcard expansion - is there anything similar for mingw64?

Comment: There is `CRT_glob.o` which you should find in either `i686-w64-mingw32/lib` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to refer to it in the compile command line by full absolute pathname? I couldn't see a way to get the linker to find it just from the base name.

Comment: Yes, you have to use the full path.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed - I've posted a copy of this information as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @ssbssa above:

There is a file `CRT_glob.o` file supplied with the mingw packages, in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/CRT_glob.o` (or the corresponding location for 32-bit) that you can link with your executable to activate command line globbing.

You have to specify the file by full pathname for the linker to find it.

Comment: I just found out how you can let gcc give you the full path: `gcc -print-file-name=CRT_glob.o`